# Get 2D position of a 3D object when it follows another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I get 2D position of a 3D object (ie. z axis should be 0) when this object is following another 3D object?

So far I have tried the below one line code but the z axis does not remain 0 since it follows another object it keeps fluctuating. Any solutions?

```
public GameObject Car;
public GameObject Icon;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    Icon.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(Car.transform.position, Car.transform.position, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Icon.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(Car.transform.position, Car.transform.position, 0);
```

this does absolutely nothing ... first of all you are move between the same positions and secondly with a speed = `0`... so basically this equals

```
Icon.transform.position = Car.transform.position;
```

---

What you wanted to do instead is eliminating the `z` component of the position vector so e.g. something like

```
Icon.transform.position = new Vector3(Car.transform.position.x, Car.transform.position.y, 0);
```

or a little trick: you can typecast it to `Vector2` which makes it "forget" the `z` value. It is than implicitely typecasted back to `Vector3` with `z=0`

```
Icon.transform.position = (Vector2) Car.transform.position;
```

Comment: Ah yes absolutely. I was stupid thinking MoveTowards works the same as Vector3.

Answer (score 0):

You just put the position in a local variable and set z to 0.

```
public GameObject Car;
public GameObject Icon;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Vector3 pos3d = Car.transform.position;
    pos3d.z = 0;
    Icon.transform.position = pos3d;
}
```